# Using IGraph in R, how to calculate highest/lowest edge attribute value from those connected to each vertex?

Tags: r, graph, igraph

I have a graph `g` which contains a bunch of nodes/vertexes, which are connected by edges, each of the edges has a particular numeric attribute value. An edge list might look like:

```r
v1 v2 att
a b 17
a c 6
a d 2
b c 9
```

For visualisation purposes I need to add the highest and lowest `att` numbers connected to each vertex (coming or going; direction doesn't matter here).

So for example I'd like to set `v$max` for a to 17 and `v$min` for a to 2, because the largest att-value of a link connected to a is 17, and the smallest is 2.

I tried some variants along the theme of this:

```r
V(g)$min=min(E(g)[incident(g,V(g), mode='total')]$att)
```

This seems to be very nearly right in that it appears to give the right answer when I try it on a single node, as in

```r
min(E(g)[incident(g,V(g)[2], mode='total')]$att)
```

but it doesn't work when I try it across all nodes. The aim is to get `V(g)$min` and `V(g)$max` set for every vertex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hopefully this is not a homework problem, you were just missing the generalization part

```
library(igraph)
library(plyr)
df <- data.frame(read.table(text="v1 v2 weight
a b 17
a c 6
a d 2
b c 9", header=T))
df$weight <- as.numeric(df$weight)

#transform df into igraph
g <- graph.data.frame(df, directed=F, vertices=NULL)    

#for each vertex, get all incidental edges, weights and use range to find min & max
ldply(V(g), function(v) range(incident(g, v, mode='total')$weight))
```

Comment: Thanks! It's not a homework problem, no, but fully homegrown (temporal graphs). I'm an engineer who is about as educated as I am ever likely to be (though not as educated as I should be, obviously: notably lapply/ldply are not currently my friend). I've accepted the answer: thanks once again!

By the way, any idea why the original approach doesn't work? I find it a little baffling - can't see the bug :)

Comment: It can work. It's just missing generalizing. You can try sapply(1:length(V(g)), function(n) min(E(g)[incident(g,V(g)[n], mode='total')]$att))